# Можно ли как-то узнать о касании в определенной области в jetpack compose , без высчитывания по координате смещения?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Делаю пианино, изучаю JetpackCompose, нужно чтобы по пианино можно было просто пальцем водить и звуки проигрывались , есть какая-то функция чтобы можно было узнать о касании клавиши или только считать координату через detectDragGestures?

Comment: Это копать в сторону `pointerInteropFilter` и `pointerInput`